# C#: How to use the Enumerable.Aggregate method

Tags: c#, time, aggregate

Lets say I have this amputated `Person` class:

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public int SOReputation { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeSpentOnSO { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I can then group on `Age` and `Country` like this:

```
    var groups = aListOfPeople.GroupBy(x => new { x.Country, x.Age });
```

Then I can output all the groups with their reputation totals like this:

```
foreach(var g in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}:{2}", 
        g.Key.Country, 
        g.Key.Age, 
        g.Sum(x => x.SOReputation));
```

My question is, how can I get a sum of the `TimeSpentOnSO` property? The `Sum` method won't work in this case since it is only for `int` and such. I thought I could use the `Aggregate` method, but just seriously can't figure out how to use it... I'm trying all kinds properties and types in various combinations but the compiler just won't recognize it.

```
foreach(var g in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}:{2}", 
        g.Key.Country, 
        g.Key.Age, 
        g.Aggregate(  what goes here??  ));
```

Have I completely missunderstood the Aggregate method? Or what is going on? Is it some other method I should use instead? Or do I have to write my own `Sum` variant for `TimeSpan`s?

And to add to the mess, what if Person is an anonymous class, a result from for example a `Select` or a `GroupJoin` statement?

---

Just figured out that I could make the `Aggregate` method work if I did a `Select` on the `TimeSpan` property first... but I find that kind of annoying... Still don't feel I understand this method at all...

```
foreach(var g in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}:{2}", 
        g.Key.Country, 
        g.Key.Age, 
        g.Select(x => x.TimeSpentOnSO)
        g.Aggregate((sum, x) => sum + y));
```

Comment: I just want to point out that Aggregate (reduce) is one of the coolest things in the world now that I've run into situations where I wanted to use it.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of Chris and Daniels answers solved it for me. I needed to initialize the TimeSpan, and I did things in the wrong order. The solution is:

```
foreach(var g in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}:{2}", 
        g.Key.Country, 
        g.Key.Age, 
        g.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (sum, x) => sum + x.TimeSpentOnSO));
```

Thanks!

And also... [D'oh!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'oh!)

Answer (score 24):

```
List<TimeSpan> list = new List<TimeSpan>
    {
        new TimeSpan(1),
        new TimeSpan(2),
        new TimeSpan(3)
    };

TimeSpan total = list.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (sum, value) => sum.Add(value));

Debug.Assert(total.Ticks == 6);
```

Comment: Initialize with TimeSpan.Zero. Very good point. This was with a list of TimeSpans though, I needed a list of something else with a TimeSpan property. But I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

```
g.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (i, p) => i + p.TimeSpentOnSO)
```

Basically, the first argument to Aggregate is an initializer, which is used as the first value of "i" in the function passed in the second argument. It'll iterate over the list, and each time, "i" will contain the total so far.

For example:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};

nums.Aggregate(0, (x,y) => x + y); // sums up the numbers, starting with 0 => 15
nums.Aggregate(0, (x,y) => x * y); // multiplies the numbers, starting with 0 => 0, because anything multiplied by 0 is 0
nums.Aggregate(1, (x,y) => x * y); // multiplies the numbers, starting with 1 => 120
```

Comment: This was with ints, which I already had kind of solved. But thanks for clearing up how to initialize it!

Comment: Sorry it was originally using ints. I misread the question, but this should work for you, as well as explain how Aggregate works in general.

Answer (score 2):

You could write `TimeSpan` `Sum` method...

```
public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> times)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromTicks(times.Sum(t => t.Ticks));
}
public static TimeSpan Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TimeSpan> selector)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromTicks(source.Sum(t => selector(t).Ticks));
}
```

Alternatively, [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) has generic-enabled `Sum` methods, so `Sum` should work on a `TimeSpan` just fine (since there is a `TimeSpan+TimeSpan=>TimeSpan` operator defined).

Just **please** don't tell me the number... it would scare me...

Comment: Yeah, that is kind of my backup path. But I would still like to learn how that Aggregate method really works. Cause it annoys me that I can't seem to use it successfully :p

Comment: And yes, let's keep that number forever secret. Never ever think about posting any sort of statistics like that here on SO :p (Although I must say my curiosity kind of wants it... but keep it private in that case!)

Answer (score 0):

You could sum on one of the Total properties of the TimeSpan.  For instance, you could get the represented TotalHours of time spent on SO like this:

```
g.Sum(x => x.SOReputation.TotalHours)
```

I believe this would give you the result you're looking for, but with the caveat that you'd have to put the units of measure according to what you need (hours, minutes, second, days, etc.)

Comment: Actually this is what I ended up doing, but for other reasons. Still happy that I finally understand the Aggregate method (Although not an expert :p).